# Str_compare -- from Irvine's assembly book

Tags: assembly, strcmp

```
    Str_compare PROC USES eax edx esi edi,
        string1: PTR BYTE,
        string2: PTR BYTE
    ;
    ; Compare two strings.
    ; Returns nothing, but the Zero and Carry flags are affected
    ; exactly as they would be by the CMP instruction.
    ;-----------------------------------------------------------
        mov  esi, string1
        mov  edi, string2
    L1: mov  al, [esi]
        mov  dl, [edi]
        cmp  al, 0
        jne  L2
        cmp  dl, 0
        jne  L2
        jmp  L3

    L2: inc  esi
        inc  edi
        cmp  al, dl
        je   L1

    L3: ret
    Str_compare ENDP
```

Against the code above, what if `string1` is just `byte 0` and `string2` is some common string whose length is not 0?
I suppose, when cpu enter L1 at the first time, IP will jump to L2 after `cmp dl, 0`. `inc esi` will make esi point to an content-unknown byte right after the 0 byte of string1, so this program break down, right?

Comment: `esi` can have any value you want, as long as you don't try to access it... which Dr. Irvine's code does not...

Comment: @FrankKotler what do you mean `Dr. Irvine's code does not...`?

Comment: Doesn't do `mov al, [esi]` after `esi` points to a "bad place". What Michael said. Learn to use a debugger or learn to think like a CPU. The latter may be easier. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `inc esi` will make `esi` point to an content-unknown byte right after the 0 byte of `string1`, so this program break down, right?

*Pointing to* X simply means *holding the address of* X. It's perfectly ok to hold a value which could be interpreted as an invalid address, as long as you don't try to dereference the pointer (i.e. read from the address).

Even if you *did* try to read from `[esi]` when `esi` points one byte beyond `string1` there would probably not be any crash. It's fairly likely that you've got other data located after `string1` which also belongs to your program, and which your program therefore has access to. So reading beyond `string1` will just read whatever happens to be there, up until some point where you go beyond the end of your program's data section or stack or wherever `string1` happens to be located.

What happens in the `Str_compare` function if one string is empty (contains only a NUL-terminator) and the other is non-empty is that `cmp  al, dl` will compare a NUL-terminator against something that is not a NUL-terminator. The conditional `je L1` will therefore not jump back to `L1`, and instead the `ret` at `L3` will be executed, causing the function to return. The incremented addresses in `esi` and `edi` will therefore not be dereferenced.

Comment: In the situation that string1 is just "\0", what would happen to this program? The second time cpu enters into L1, it compares 0 with an unknown value(which is [esi]), so is this a bug?

Comment: In the case where `string1` is an empty string (`'\0'`) and `string2` is a non-empty string, `cmp  al, dl` on the first iteration would not set the ZF, so `je   L1` would not jump, and hence `ret` would be executed, thereby exiting the `Str_compare` routine.

Comment: But `inc esi` and `inc edi` have been excuted before `cmp al, dl`, how can we know whether `[esi]` equals to `[edi]` or not? Assuming, `string2[1]` is 0x1 and the byte right after string1 is 0x1 either.

Comment: `cmp al,dl` does not read from `[esi]` or `[edi]`. Those reads were done when you did `mov  al, [esi]` and `mov  dl, [edi]`, which happened before you incremented the pointers.